# Need to downgrade to Werkzeug==2.3.7 from Werkzeug==3.0.0 to avoid werkzeug/http.py TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I have a docker image flask web application which is generating the error below after rebuilding the docker image and deploying the docker container from it.
Before today, the containers from the images built using the docker file and requirements.txt file as this image ran without any errors.
I suspect there may have been a recent python module update in the image I built today that is causing the error below.

The Python version is Python 3.12.0

The output of pip list is shown below.

```
root@8015f43d01aa:/# pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
blinker            1.6.2
cachelib           0.10.2
certifi            2023.7.22
charset-normalizer 3.3.0
click              8.1.7
Flask              2.3.3
Flask-PyMongo      2.3.0
Flask-Session      0.5.0
gunicorn           21.2.0
idna               3.4
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.3
packaging          23.2
pika               1.3.2
pip                23.2.1
psycopg2           2.9.8
pyasn1             0.5.0
pyasn1-modules     0.3.0
pymongo            3.12.3
python-dateutil    2.8.2
python-ldap        3.4.3
redis              5.0.1
requests           2.31.0
setuptools         68.2.2
six                1.16.0
urllib3            2.0.6
Werkzeug           3.0.0
wheel              0.41.2
```

The error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1487, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1508, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2005, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 454, in save_session
    response.set_cookie(app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_NAME"], session_id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/sansio/response.py", line 224, in set_cookie
    dump_cookie(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 1303, in dump_cookie
    if not _cookie_no_quote_re.fullmatch(value):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Downgrading to Werkzeug==2.3.7 from Werkzeug==3.0.0 solved the above error.
Werkzeug==3.0.0 was released 2023-September-30.

Comment: Got bitten with this as well on a old Flask 2.2.x. Flask defines its dependency on Werkzeug with no upper bound on the version. So there is always a risk whenever there is a release that we get some regression.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to Werkzeug==2.3.7 from Werkzeug==3.0.0 solved the above error. Werkzeug==3.0.0 was released 2023-September-30.

Comment: In the long term this is not an option. Once you go for `Flask 3.x`, you can no longer apply this "fix".

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to `flask==3.0.1` and `werkzeug==3.0.1` (and `flask-session==0.6.0`) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the cookie value that is passed to `set_cookie()` is cast to string. Byte-like objects would previously work but cause this error in the latest Werkzeug version.